# Classification of complex objects

Tags: sql, algorithm, classification

I have set of objects:

```
class someObject {
   float weight; //can be from 0.0 to 1000000.0
   enum type {A, B, C};
   int code; //can be from 0 to 1000
}
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE `someObjects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `weight` float NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('A','B','C') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

The set contains 1,000 such objects.

How to split this set into groups of **9** objects by these rules:

- Objects should be very close to each other by **weight**;
- Each group should contains approximately equal number of **types**, 3 x
  (A, B and C);
- Objects with the same **code** must be in the same groups.

Is it possible to solve this problem using only **SQL**?

What classification algorithm should I choose using SQL with PHP or C++?

Comment: what are you using. MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle?

Comment: This problem is not well-suited for SQL.  SQL problems are usually deterministic (like "list all the possibles ways of splitting these into 9 groups") versus optimization (like "what is the best way . . .").  This is in the class of bin-packing problems.  A typical algorithm for them is the greedy algorithm.  More about bin-packing problems here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very easy to create sets of 1000 objects that defy the kind of grouping that you're looking for, given your rules.  But perhaps the data has characteristics that mean your rules do make sense, in which case to get a good answer to the problem you somehow need to incorporate that extra information.

When I've tackled these kind of problems in the past, I've usually managed to get [K-Means clustering to work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).  However I've never tried to do it in SQL, but it would be interesting to try.